# Counting the number of unique words in a dataframe with Python

Tags: python, pandas, count, unique

I'm Python newbie. I didn't a solution for the following problem :

I got this type of dataframe which represents a sequence of touchpoint  :

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'path' : ['a>b>c','b>b','c>c','b>d','a>c>c']})

    path
    a>b>c
    b>b
    c>c
    b>d
    a>c>c
```

I neeed to count the number of unique touchpoint for each row and obtain :

```
    path    count_unique_touchpoint
    a>b>c   3
    b>b     1
    c>c     1
    b>d     2
    a>c>c   2
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to split the strings around the delimiter `>` then use [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) to apply a custom function which maps each of the item of this series to the number of distinct elements it contains. Use:

```
df["count_unique_touchpoint"] = df["path"].str.split(">").apply(lambda s: len(set(s)))
print(df)
```

This prints:

```
    path  count_unique_touchpoint
0  a>b>c                        3
1    b>b                        1
2    c>c                        1
3    b>d                        2
4  a>c>c                        2
```

Comment: Crystal clear. Many thanks for our quick and efficient answer.